# How to send the error message from Vuex action to component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

The code looks as following:

**Vuex action:**

```
async save({ commit, state, dispatch }: ActionCtx): Promise<boolean> {
  const { entity, updateStack, $options } = state;
  const saveResult = await saveEntity('fbCities', entity, updateStack, $options);
  console.log('SAVE RESULT =', saveResult);
  if (saveResult === false) return false;
  if (typeof saveResult === 'string') return dispatch('load', saveResult);
  commit('update entity', saveResult);
  return true;
}
```

**Vue component:**

```
saveClick() {
  try {
    this.$store.dispatch('Handbook/City/save');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR =', error);
  }
```

When the error occures `saveResult` is false. The error in catch block doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An action cannot return a result, it always returns a promise of undefined. If an error is expected on fail, it should be thrown:

```
  if (saveResult === false)
    throw new Error('No result');
```

Otherwise empty result should be processed a kind of result and be stored and accessed in a store, e.g. as `null` value.